# nginx is not serving react build correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack

I have multi stage docker file.

I build the react app in the 1st stage, and serve via nginx in the 2nd stage.

My 1st stage is fine, I can see the app. The 2nd stage runs without errors, but I only get the `Welcome to nginx!` screen. Any idea why this may be?

I am using react and webpack.

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build
# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

```
server {
  listen 80;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location = / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

```
/* globals __dirname:false, module:false */

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
    entry: __dirname + '/src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader", "ts-loader"],
            },
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        static: {
            directory: __dirname + '/public'
        },
        proxy: {
            '/users': {
                target: 'http://localhost:5500/'
            }
        },
        port: 3000
    }
};
```

Comment: is the path to your nginx.conf correct? also does it say anything in the nginx container?and look at the nginx.conf in the container to verify that it really changed the conf

Comment: another thing would be that the root in the .conf does not point to a public folder     root /var/www/public; is usually in my .conf and the app gets copied to var/www im certain that its a root problem